# JQuery Popup Form not closing

Tags: jquery, web, popup

```
       $(document).ready(function() {

       $('a.register-window').click(function () {
           var popupBox = $(this).attr('href');
           $(popupBox).fadeIn(400);

           var popupMarginTop = ($(popupBox).height() + 24)/2;
           var popupMarginLeft = ($(popupBox).width() + 24)/2;

           $(popupBox).css({

               'margin-top' : -popupMarginTop,
               'margin-left' : -popupMarginLeft

           });

           $('body').append('<div id="screen-shadow"></div>');
           $('#screen-shadow').fadeIn(300);
           return false;

       });

       $('button.close, #screen-shadow').live('click', function() {

           $('#screen-shadow , .register-popup').fadeOut(300, function() {

               $('#screen-shadow').remove();

           });

           return false;
       });

       });
```

Above is the Jquery code which I use to show a popup login form for a forum. I manage to show the popup with this code just fine but closing it does not work by clicking the button or clicking on the (screen-shadow) which is basically a mask. I will greatly appreciate some help on this :).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `on()` instead of `live()`. You can try like below

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.close, #screen-shadow', function() {
    $('#screen-shadow, .register-popup').fadeOut(300, function() {
        $('#screen-shadow').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the opening and closing of brackets, Prentiss etc. it seems that you forgot something in your code..